# Spring application - Override app properties by test properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm new to spring and will really appreciate if someone can help me through this.

I've a spring boot application App1 which has the following db properties in main and test packages respectively:

```
src/main/resources/app1.properties

src/test/resources/app1-test.properties
```

Let's suppose app1.properties contain oracle db properties and app1-test.properties contain h2 db properties

Normally,when I startup the App1 application, it picks up properties from app1.properties

What my requirement is that when I create a test instance of the application (say TestApp1), then the app1-test.properties should be chosen and not the app1.properties.

How can I achieve this? Kindly help.

Comment: both properties will be be included when you build the app. Its when you start the app you can run it with a profile `java -jar myApp.jar --spring.profiles=test`

Comment: here you can read about profiles: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to when running test classes for your application you can include the annotation @ActiveProfiles("test") above the class to include the app1-test.properties configuration.

The top of the class should look something like this:

```
    @ActiveProfiles("test")
    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
    @SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
    public class YourTestClassName {
```

Answer (score 0):

@domorecalculus's answer looks good. Although, since I've actually never used @ActiveProfile I'll go ahead and post an alternative in case that's not what you're looking for:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
@SpringBootTest
public class InvalidTransactionTests {
    ...
}
```

One advantage might be that this annotation separates your `src/main/test` from your `src/main/java` entirely. A disadvantage (I could be wrong about this) might be that the base name 'application.properties' is ambiguous given that that file already exists in `src/main/java`.

Answer (score 0):

Put property file in same location as application.property and follow the naming convention appliaction-{profile}.properties like application-dev.properties,application-test.properties, application-prod.properties

And in application.properties set spring.profiles.active=test for using test properties and for dev properties you can set spring.profiles.active=dev and by default application.properties will be picked

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @domorecalculus, the standard way to do it is using Spring profiles. I advise you to dig more in Spring Profiles, it will give you flexibility not only at the configuration level but also at the code level e.g you can annotate a class with @Profile(value = "dev"), so that class will be loaded when running your application in dev mode only. You can think about it as an implementation of the Strategy Pattern, but you can't change the profile at runtime.

Back to your question, I used to do it in the following way:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApp.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TestMyService { 
 .....
}
```